# SQL Delete with SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-delete

I've got the following select query:

```
SELECT opt.product_option_id 
FROM  `oc_product_option_value` AS opt_val,  `oc_product_option` AS opt
WHERE  `opt`.`product_option_id` =  `opt_val`.`product_option_id` 
AND  `opt_val`.`price` =  '0.0000'
```

I thought that i could use that in an `delete` query:

```
DELETE oc_product_option, oc_product_option_value FROM oc_product_option 
INNER JOIN oc_product_option_value

WHERE  `oc_product_option`.`product_option_id` =  `oc_product_option_value`.`product_option_id` 
AND  `oc_product_option_value`.`price` =  '0.0000'
```

But that deleted ALL rows in `oc_product_option`. So what did i do wrong?

Comment: Everything in `oc_product_option` had a price of `'0.0000'` would be my first guess.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, That's not true. There is no `price` table in `oc_product_option`. In the second table (`oc_product_option_value` ), there are prices that are indeed `0.0000`, but there's also some with price `0.8260`...

Comment: [Your code works fine](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a38fb/1/0). My only guess would be Gordon's first.

Comment: @Mathlight . . . That would be the `oc_product_option_value` table.  Another option is that you are running only the first two or three lines of the query and not all four of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you give this a try?

```
DELETE t1 FROM oc_product_option t1
JOIN oc_product_option_value t2
WHERE  `t1`.`product_option_id` =  `t2`.`product_option_id` 
AND  `t2`.`price` =  '0.0000'
```

Is it the intetion to delete the rows of both tables?

Comment: If you want to delete from both tables just name them both after the `DELETE` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You make a circular dependence and this is why you get this result

Bellow query should delete only rows that have id in oc_product_option and price zero.
Or you have to define range of ids in oc_product_option using another criteria to filter oc_product_option table

```
DELETE FROM oc_product_option o
 WHERE  o.product_option_id in (SELECT opt.product_option_id FROM oc_product_option_value
                                 where `oc_product_option_value`.`price` =  '0.0000')
```

Comment: You cannot use the same table you are deleting from in the subquery. I think this will cause error.

Comment: The query doesn't make any sense anyway